# PostgreSQL - Convert string to ASCII integer

Tags: postgresql, ascii, sqldatatypes

How do I get the ASCII value of a string as an int in PostgreSQL?

For example: the string S06.6X9A

Currently, I am using an ASCII function, but it returns only the first character of a given string.

Comment: `S06.6X9A` is not a single integer. Do you want it as the `int` array `[83, 48, 54, 46, 54, 88, 57, 65]`? Could you provide an example of the output you want?

Comment: Yup, I want it as the int array. For example: after converting, the expected result as: 8348544654885765

Comment: You can use the technique in my answer and turning the table back into an array, but you're probably better off writing a function and using `foreach` to do it more directly. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-FOREACH-ARRAY

Comment: thanks a lot! It's really helpful for a beginner like me!

Comment: You're welcome. SQL is mind bending, but it's worth it. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `string_to_array('S06.6X9A', null)` to split the string into a `text[]` of individual characters. Then `unnest` to turn that `text[]` into a table. Then use that in a `from` clause and run `ascii()` over each row.

```
select ascii(char)
from (
  select unnest( string_to_array('S06.6X9A', null) )
) as chars(char);

 ascii 
-------
    83
    48
    54
    46
    54
    88
    57
    65
```

Answer (score 3):

Simpler than Schwern's answer is:

```
SELECT ascii( unnest( string_to_array('S06.6X9A', NULL) ) )
```

Comment: Technically this is identical to Schwern's answer and using set returning functions in the SELECT list is discouraged though.