# SQL query for all possible pairs from a single column

Tags: sql

I am working on an SQL query where I am looking for all possible combinations.
My table looks like this:

Table: Fruits

```
|ID  |  Name |
|1   | Apple |
|2   | Banana|
|3   | Cherry|
|4   | Peach |
```

I am trying to get the out put of all possible combinations of two of the fruits with no repeats (ie, if there is Apple, Banana then I do not want Banana, Apple):

```
Apple, Apple
Apple, Banana
Apple, Cherry
...
Cherry, Peach
Peach, Peach
```

All I have so far is a way to make two rows of Fruits

```
SELECT Name AS Fruit1, Name AS Fruit2
FROM Fruits
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: This is a `SELF JOIN` exercise.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Just test for less than in the join.

Answer (score 1):

You can just join the tables. The syntax depends a little bit on the db you are using. This should work on most SQL databases:

```
   SELECT f1.name AS Fruit1,
          f2.name AS Fruit2
   FROM Fruits f1
   JOIN Fruits f2 ON f1.name <= f2.name
```

Comment: The OP want's *unordered* pairs: "... if there is Apple, Banana then I do not want Banana, Apple ...". This solution doesn't respect that.

Comment: Thanks. I missed that. I have updated the example.

Comment: Now "Apple, Apple" will be missing, they have that in their expected result... And I suggest to put the expression in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause. It's clearer there.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following cross join and filter

```
select t1.name, t2.name
from t t1
cross join t t2
where t2.id=t1.id or t2.id>t1.id
order by t1.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this with Postgresql but I think you can use the same logic with another database if you don't use postgres.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION get_str_ascii(char[]) RETURNS int8 AS $$
    DECLARE
      s int8 := 0;
      x char;
    BEGIN
      FOREACH x IN ARRAY $1
      LOOP
        s := s + ascii(x);
      END LOOP;
      RETURN s;
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select MAX(tab.f1), MIN(tab.f2)  from (
    select 
        f1.name as f1, 
        f2.name as f2, 
        get_str_ascii(string_to_array(f1.name||f2.name, null)) as ascii_total from fruits f1
    inner join fruits f2 on true
) tab
group by tab.ascii_total
```

1. Calculate Ascii summatory of every fruit for that I created a function, it allowed me to know if two entries are repeated example the ascii summatory for **applecherry** is the same than for **cherryapple** 1183
2. Group by ascii total summatory column and get the MAX and MIN of every entries for example

```
fruit1 fruit2 ascii_total
cherry apple 1183
apple cherry 1183
```

If I get the max of fruit1 and fruit2 I would get

```
fruit1 fruit2
cherry cherry
```

for that reason I used MAX and MIN

I was stucking to figure out how to transform a string into a ascii summatory, this thread helped me: [PostgreSQL - Convert string to ASCII integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62137674/postgresql-convert-string-to-ascii-integer)

Comment: I can't anwer to @Stu answer, but It looks more elegant!